# Replace String not work

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring

I need to add the string @"d" after "id="

Example  =

```
url = @"id=63488320543140151742289377"
```

needs to be

```
url = @"id=d63488320543140151742289377"
```

I have tried this:

```
NSRange range = [url rangeOfString:@"id="];
[url stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"id=d"];
```

but not work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
url = [url stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"id=" withString:@"id=d"];
```

Answer (score 2):

`stringByReplacingCharactersInRange` returns a string.  Your code should work if you assign the new string that's returned to some variable (e.g. `url = [url stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@"id=d"];`)

Comment: I have tried    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"id=" withString:@"id=d"]; but forgot url = ...thx!